# Show that the following matrix is PSD

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

I would like to show that:

$$\pmatrix{\mathbf{Y} \mathbf{Y}^{\top}  &  \mathbf{Y} \mathbf{Z}^{\top}\\  \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{Y}^{\top} &  \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{Z}^{\top}} \succeq \mathbf{0}$$

where $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $\mathbf{Z} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times m}$.

I try to use Schur complement, but could not proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your matrix as $AA^T$ where $A$ is the block matrix
$$A=\pmatrix{Y\\Z}.$$